# How to make Zend_Auth case insensitive to username?

Tags: zend-framework, postgresql, authentication, zend-auth

Is there a way to make Zend_Auth to accept case-insensetive identities(i.e. usernames)? Zend_Auth seems to provide a way to add special treatment to a credential field, but not to identity field.

PS: I am using Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable that points to Postgres table.

Comment: Hi @Alex N. i face same issue can you see my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47300930/how-to-make-username-case-insensitive-in-zf2 as you already face this issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$authAdapter = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable(
       $dbAdapter,
       'usertable',
       new Zend_Db_Expr('LOWER(username)'),
       'password'
);

$authAdapter
   ->setIdentity(strtolower($this->_getParam('username'))
   ->setCredential($this->_getParam('password'));
```

And be sure to use one of the ***_ci** collations in your database for username field (ci = case-insensitive).
Hope it helps

Comment: +1. And it would be nice to wrap this into a custom auth adapter extending `Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable` with a simpler constructor `public function __construct($dbAdapter)` and an overridden `setIdentity()` method. See http://pastebin.com/a6KnhKw8.

Comment: Hi @David i face same problem can you see my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47300930/how-to-make-username-case-insensitive-in-zf2 any help appreciable

Answer (score 0):

You could alter your table so the username column is of type [citext](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/citext.html) so it is case-insensitive and you still get the benefit of using the index.

Comment: Hi @drew010 can you see my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47300930/how-to-make-username-case-insensitive-in-zf2   any help appreciable